# Zapier workaround to send Gmail updates to Slack

Tags: gmail, slack, zapier

On Zapier, I tried to setup a Zap to forward Gmail email bodies to a private Slack channel. Apparently, this used to be supported, but no longer. Can anyone suggest a workaround to achieve the same goal?

[image: Zapier error]